# How to set the Tab Order in Swing Java?

Tags: java, swing

I want to know how to adjust the Tab order in a Swing interface. I found an example and it showed this method should do the trick but it seems that it's deprecated and not working.

```
getCombox("cmbFrom").setNextFocusableComponent(getCombox("cmbTo"));
```

Note :- Below method returns a Combox object with the Argument name. If someone knows how to do it with Netbeans IDE it would be great. I found a way to do it in Eclipse WindowBuilder but not in Netbeans IDE. Thank you.

```
getCombox(String s)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [`setFocusTraversalPolicy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setFocusTraversalPolicy%28java.awt.FocusTraversalPolicy%29) in your container.

[`FocusTraversalPolicy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FocusTraversalPolicy.html) class is abstract and you need implement few methods which will return the container's component focus order. It will work with Tab and Shift + Tab.

Comment: It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).

Comment: +1 for FTP, but better not start from FocusTraversalPolicy, there's too much that can go wrong. Better start from any of the concrete implementations (f.i. SortingFocusTraversalPolicy) and override as needed (f.i. plug-in a custom comparator)

Comment: fyi, just checked the tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#customFocusTraversal - that chapter is still as bad as it was from start. To see the misbehaviour of the overly naive implementation, replace f.i. textField tf4 with an editable comboBox ...

Comment: How to prevent the component from keeping focus inside it? If I set `setFocusCycleRoot()` to `true`, user can not exit from the container (unless with Ctrl+Tab, which is not expected from users). Although `getComponentAfter()` returns true on the last focus child, focus moves to the first focus child, and vica versa.

Answer (score 8):

if you are using netbeans select the first component that you want to be the first focused element and in properties make sure focusCycleRoot is ticked.
and in the nextFocusableComponent choose the next component that you want to gain focus when you press tab and go ahead the same way for other component

Note: do not check the focusCycleRooot for the other component

Comment: aahaaaaaa i tried but without focuscycleroot thanks jafaritaqi

Comment: Works without `focusCycleRoot`