# How do I move focus textfield in Compiere (Adepiere)

Tags: java, focus, textfield, adempiere

After the clicking on the tab I need to move the cursor focus from textfield X to textfield Y, but not to the next as the default. 
Let me explain:

**textfield1** - textfield - textfield3 - textfield4

***press tab (default)***
textfield1 - **textfield2** - textfield3 - textfield4

***press tab (my version)***
textfield1 - textfield2 - textfield3 - **textfield4**

By default if the focus is on textfield1 and I click on tab the focus goes on textfield2, I want it to go to textfield4.
does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: maybe this will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480363/how-to-set-the-tab-order-in-swing-java

Comment: It wasn't the configuration change. If you need this requirement you need to do explicit changes on code. There is one option, It will never focus if textfields are readonly.(It will not work for readonly logic fields).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a hardcode event for this textfield1. ADempiere framework doens't have support for this action for now.