# Customising what happens when pressing 'tab' in Netbeans Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

So I am building an login frame using Netbeans 8.1. The problem is that after the user has typed in their username, I want them to be able to press the tab key and then have the password textField selected, but instead of this, the 'Login' button is selected.

On startup the username field is selected.

[Then when I press tab it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf1LK.png)

[But instead I want it to look like this when I press tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zLOQ.png)

Any help is welcome, but I would prefer it if I can do this without getting into the code and can use the Netbeans GUI instead(the project is only about designing the GUI, and nothing about the actual code).

Comment: Start with [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need order your component indexes, it calls tab index.

NetBeans 8.0 I believe the first component (ie. textBox) you add to the design window should be the one the cursor defaults to when you run the program. You can set the order for tabbing from component to component when you run the program in the design window. Select the first component. In the Properties window, go to nextFocusableComponent and choose the next component you want to tab to in the dropdown list. Repeat for rest of components

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for, and quite easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9480493/1153988).

You can implement your own [`FocusTraversalPolicy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FocusTraversalPolicy.html) which will manage the tab order. You can then assign it to your frame with the `setFocusTraversalPolicy` method.

You can find [some more explanations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#customFocusTraversal) in Oracle's doc.

Answer (score -1):

No Tab key-pressed or key-released events are received by the key event listener. This is because the focus subsystem consumes focus traversal keys, such as Tab and Shift Tab.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

To solve this, apply the following to the component that is firing the key events (e.g., the TextArea):

.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false)

Using this method, you must then handle focus traversal explicitly. Alternatively, the KeyEventDispatcher class can be used to pre-listen to all key events.

**you can do following way also**

```
txtUserName.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg)
        {
        if (arg.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
            txtPassword.requestFocus();
        }
        }
    });
    txtPassword.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg)
        {
        if (arg.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
            btnLogin.doClick();
        }
        }
});
```

Comment: `KeyListener` is a poor choice generally, Swing has a well documented focus management API and [Enter] isn't always the prescribed "transfer" key

Comment: then which is best way to do so

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)